# OverlayFS - Is it possible to make overlay layer writable by anyone/specific user (different than original owner)?

Tags: permissions, overlayfs

#### Usecase:

I have a lot of production data and copying it for dev purposes would be unreal. I was thinking that OverlayFS could be a solution until a problem with permissions arised.

Let's assume i have following folder structure:

- `/data/prod` - production data (files+subfolders) owned by `prod:prod` having `664`
- `/data/prod-overlay/dev1/{overlay,upper,lower}` - data for developers (user `dev1:dev1` in this case)

Dev users can read prod data but not modify.

#### My question is:

Is it possible to make files in `/data/overlayfs/developer1/overlay` writable even when permissions of original files do not allow it? Or is there any other (simple) way to achieve such behaviour while keeping prod data read-only for dev users?

**For example:**

There is a file `/data/prod/subfolder/file` (`prod:prod`, `664`) and user `dev1` wants to remove or change `/data/prod-overlay/dev1/overlay/subfolder/file`.

Note: `dev1` can remove file `/data/prod-overlay/dev1/overlay/file` (with `rm -f`) probably because he is the owner of the overlay folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer for my question.

The solution is to use **overlayfs** in combination with **[bindfs](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs-help.txt)** that allows mount one folder as another folder with different perms/owner/etc.

```bsh
# sudo bindfs --map=origOwner/newOwner:@origGroup/@newGroup /srcFolder /dstMountpoint

mkdir /data/prod-overlay/dev1/prod  # mountpoint
sudo bindfs --map=prod/dev1:@prod/@dev1 /data/prod-overlay/dev1/overlay /data/prod-overlay/dev1/prod
```